# Tensorflow fit and evaulate gap

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I built a classification model with Tensorflow. Training is done with 1 batch per epoch. Shuffle is set to off while loading from directories. When doing evaluate on the training data, the fit metrics are different from the one shown by the evaluate (Accuracy in particular).

Why metrics are different between fit and evaluate while on the same dataset?

```
seed=1
#import validation picture with B&W between -1 and 1
VALIDATION_DIR="../input/validbottom"

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=prep_fn
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    VALIDATION_DIR,
    target_size=sizepictures,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode="grayscale",
    seed=seed,
    shuffle=False
)


#import validation picture with B&W between -1 and 1
TRAINING_DIR="../input/trainbottom"

training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=prep_fn
)

training_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAINING_DIR,
    target_size=sizepictures,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode="grayscale",
    seed=seed,
    shuffle=False
)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[450, 100, 1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='rmsprop', 
              metrics=['CategoricalCrossentropy', 'CategoricalAccuracy','Accuracy', 'TruePositives', 'TrueNegatives', 'FalsePositives', 'FalseNegatives' ])

early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    min_delta=0.1, # minimium amount of change to count as an improvement
    patience=6, # how many epochs to wait before stopping
    restore_best_weights=True,
    monitor='val_Accuracy',
    mode='max'
)

history = model.fit(
    training_generator, 
    epochs=50, 
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    verbose=1, 
    validation_steps =1,
    steps_per_epoch=1,
    #shuffle=False,
    callbacks=[early_stopping] # put your callbacks in a list
    )
```

Outcome is the following:

```
Found 84 images belonging to 4 classes.
Found 489 images belonging to 4 classes.
Model: "sequential_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
flatten_8 (Flatten)          (None, 45000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 512)               23040512  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 4)                 2052      
=================================================================
Total params: 23,042,564
Trainable params: 23,042,564
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/50
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 0.8071 - categorical_crossentropy: 0.8071 - categorical_accuracy: 0.5556 - Accuracy: 0.5556 - true_positives: 3.0000 - true_negatives: 25.0000 - false_positives: 2.0000 - false_negatives: 6.0000 - val_loss: 1232.6909 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 1232.6909 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_Accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_true_positives: 0.0000e+00 - val_true_negatives: 64.0000 - val_false_positives: 32.0000 - val_false_negatives: 32.0000
Epoch 2/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 363ms/step - loss: 1560.4690 - categorical_crossentropy: 1560.4690 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - Accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - true_positives: 0.0000e+00 - true_negatives: 64.0000 - false_positives: 32.0000 - false_negatives: 32.0000 - val_loss: 667.5890 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 667.5890 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_Accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_true_positives: 0.0000e+00 - val_true_negatives: 64.0000 - val_false_positives: 32.0000 - val_false_negatives: 32.0000
Epoch 3/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 334ms/step - loss: 14.1437 - categorical_crossentropy: 14.1437 - categorical_accuracy: 0.9688 - Accuracy: 0.9688 - true_positives: 31.0000 - true_negatives: 95.0000 - false_positives: 1.0000 - false_negatives: 1.0000 - val_loss: 662.7253 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 662.7253 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_Accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_true_positives: 0.0000e+00 - val_true_negatives: 64.0000 - val_false_positives: 32.0000 - val_false_negatives: 32.0000
Epoch 4/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 412ms/step - loss: 1120.9546 - categorical_crossentropy: 1120.9546 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0625 - Accuracy: 0.0625 - true_positives: 2.0000 - true_negatives: 66.0000 - false_positives: 30.0000 - false_negatives: 30.0000 - val_loss: 626.6716 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 626.6716 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2188 - val_Accuracy: 0.2188 - val_true_positives: 7.0000 - val_true_negatives: 71.0000 - val_false_positives: 25.0000 - val_false_negatives: 25.0000
Epoch 5/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 425ms/step - loss: 695.7236 - categorical_crossentropy: 695.7236 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - Accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - true_positives: 0.0000e+00 - true_negatives: 64.0000 - false_positives: 32.0000 - false_negatives: 32.0000 - val_loss: 207.2412 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 207.2412 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5938 - val_Accuracy: 0.5938 - val_true_positives: 19.0000 - val_true_negatives: 83.0000 - val_false_positives: 13.0000 - val_false_negatives: 13.0000
Epoch 6/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 433ms/step - loss: 209.9644 - categorical_crossentropy: 209.9644 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1562 - Accuracy: 0.1562 - true_positives: 5.0000 - true_negatives: 69.0000 - false_positives: 27.0000 - false_negatives: 27.0000 - val_loss: 275.6523 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 275.6523 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2500 - val_Accuracy: 0.2500 - val_true_positives: 8.0000 - val_true_negatives: 72.0000 - val_false_positives: 24.0000 - val_false_negatives: 24.0000
Epoch 7/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 367ms/step - loss: 198.0545 - categorical_crossentropy: 198.0545 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2500 - Accuracy: 0.2500 - true_positives: 8.0000 - true_negatives: 72.0000 - false_positives: 24.0000 - false_negatives: 24.0000 - val_loss: 208.0038 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 208.0038 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5938 - val_Accuracy: 0.5938 - val_true_positives: 19.0000 - val_true_negatives: 83.0000 - val_false_positives: 13.0000 - val_false_negatives: 13.0000
Epoch 8/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 354ms/step - loss: 350.3277 - categorical_crossentropy: 350.3277 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2188 - Accuracy: 0.2188 - true_positives: 7.0000 - true_negatives: 71.0000 - false_positives: 25.0000 - false_negatives: 25.0000 - val_loss: 555.0655 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 555.0655 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.2500 - val_Accuracy: 0.2500 - val_true_positives: 8.0000 - val_true_negatives: 72.0000 - val_false_positives: 24.0000 - val_false_negatives: 24.0000
Epoch 9/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 351ms/step - loss: 809.6168 - categorical_crossentropy: 809.6168 - categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - Accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - true_positives: 0.0000e+00 - true_negatives: 64.0000 - false_positives: 32.0000 - false_negatives: 32.0000 - val_loss: 374.6082 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 374.6082 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1562 - val_Accuracy: 0.1562 - val_true_positives: 5.0000 - val_true_negatives: 69.0000 - val_false_positives: 27.0000 - val_false_negatives: 27.0000
Epoch 10/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 362ms/step - loss: 130.3355 - categorical_crossentropy: 130.3355 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3438 - Accuracy: 0.3438 - true_positives: 11.0000 - true_negatives: 75.0000 - false_positives: 21.0000 - false_negatives: 21.0000 - val_loss: 295.7922 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 295.7922 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1250 - val_Accuracy: 0.1250 - val_true_positives: 4.0000 - val_true_negatives: 68.0000 - val_false_positives: 28.0000 - val_false_negatives: 28.0000
Epoch 11/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 406ms/step - loss: 11.9628 - categorical_crossentropy: 11.9628 - categorical_accuracy: 0.7812 - Accuracy: 0.7812 - true_positives: 25.0000 - true_negatives: 89.0000 - false_positives: 7.0000 - false_negatives: 7.0000 - val_loss: 267.0844 - val_categorical_crossentropy: 267.0844 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.1250 - val_Accuracy: 0.1250 - val_true_positives: 4.0000 - val_true_negatives: 68.0000 - val_false_positives: 28.0000 - val_false_negatives: 28.0000
```

My understanding is that it should take weights fro epoch 5. This Epoch is having val_Accuracy: 0.5938.

If we now look to evaluate:

```
# Use the validation generator without shuffle to easily compute additional metrics
TEST_DIR="../input/validbottom"

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=prep_fn
)

test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TEST_DIR,
    target_size=sizepictures,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode="grayscale",
    seed=seed,
    shuffle=False
)


# Evaluate the model on the test data using `evaluate`
print("Evaluate on test data")
results = model.evaluate(test_datagen, batch_size=84)
print("test loss, test acc:", results)
```

Outcome is the following:

```
Found 84 images belonging to 4 classes.
Evaluate on test data
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 66ms/step - loss: 321.6571 - categorical_crossentropy: 321.6571 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3452 - Accuracy: 0.3452 - true_positives: 29.0000 - true_negatives: 197.0000 - false_positives: 55.0000 - false_negatives: 55.0000
test loss, test acc: [321.6571350097656, 321.6571350097656, 0.3452380895614624, 0.3452380895614624, 29.0, 197.0, 55.0, 55.0]
```

Accuracy show: Accuracy: 0.3452

I have the same kind of behaviour if I put validation_datagen directly into the evaluate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to be converged your optimization, you need to carefully follow the loss values to understand how it's going. At the moment this is you one:

[image]

which to me seems everything but right...

Comment: All the samples have this size (although unusual I agree)

Comment: Agreed this is not converging. Shouldn't the evaluate result be in line with the fit anyway ?

Comment: @caveman77 no, you are on a random region of space, nobody can tell you how that  region behaves